# How do you include SCSS on a Linux host (GoDaddy)?

Tags: sass

I am having an issue with SCSS on GoDaddy. I created a simple webpage on Codepen and moved all of it to GoDaddy, but I can't get the CSS to work because I don't know how to import SCSS...

Can you import it at all? As it is a compiler, not a library...?

Comment: You need to compile the SCSS and host the resulting vanilla CSS.

Comment: Codepen compiles your scss. Just save the resulting CSS file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://sass-lang.com/guide):

> it will take your preprocessed Sass file and save it as a normal CSS file that you can use in your web site
>
> The most direct way to make this happen is in your terminal. Once Sass is installed, you can run `sass input.scss output.css` from your terminal.

So the hosting doesn't really matter. You convert to CSS at build time, and then upload the static CSS file with the rest of your site.